# Facebook SDK 4.0.1 on Rubymotion

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk, rubymotion

I'm getting the following when I'm trying to compile my RubyMotion project with Facebook SDK 4.0.1

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_NSString", referenced from:

....

     (maybe you meant: _Init_NSString, _NSStringFromFBSDKLikeControlHorizontalAlignment , _NSStringFromFBSDKAppGroupPrivacy , _NSStringFromFBSDKShareDialogMode , _NSStringFromFBSDKLikeControlAuxiliaryPosition , _NSStringFromFBSDKLikeControlStyle , _NSStringFromFBSDKLikeObjectType )
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer...]
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/builder.rb:329:in `build'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/app.rb:78:in `build'
/Users/abdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/motion-cocoapods-1.7.0/lib/motion/project/cocoapods.rb:53:in `build_with_cocoapods'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/template/ios.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/template/ios.rb:186:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/abdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/abdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => build:simulator
```

I have the following in my Rakefile

```
  app.libs << '/usr/lib/libz.1.1.3.dylib'
  app.frameworks    = ["UIKit", "Foundation", 'AdSupport', 'Accounts', 'Social','CFNetwork','CoreData']
  app.weak_frameworks += %w{ AdSupport Accounts Social }

  app.pods do
    pod 'AFNetworking'
    pod 'Bolts'
    pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 4.0.0'#, '~> 3.16.0'
  end
```

I've seen some of the solutions there but am wondering if there is a cleaner one (I'm also wondering what's causing the error):

http://community.rubymotion.com/t/who-has-successfully-integrated-facebook-ios-sdk-v4-0/271

Comment: Hey, were you able to fix that?